# Why is my Rails app using chunked transfer encoding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, streaming, chunked-encoding, chunked, http-chunked

I am not using `stream` anywhere in my app, but responses are still being sent with `transfer-encoding: chunked`

additional mystery #1: the header is lowercase

additional mystery #2: there is an `etag`, which by default in rails is calculated using the md5 of the body, which is impossible to do in the streaming case.

**more info**

- rails 4.0.1
- jruby 1.7.6 in 1.9.3 mode
- heroku
- puma

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? Which webserver? Which environment?

Comment: @NielsB. see more info above